# Django- how to find what is the validation error in admin panel form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

i have a custom user model. I have written a custom ModelAdmin for that. the following is ModelAdmin:

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):

    form = UserAdminChangeForm
    # add_form = UserAdminCreationForm

    list_display = ['complete_name', 'phone_number', 'admin', 'staff']
    list_filter = ['admin', 'staff', 'is_active']
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('phone_number', 'password')}),
        ('Personals', {'fields': ('complete_name', 'email', 
'expertise', 'image_profile')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('admin', 'staff', 'is_active',)}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': (
            'phone_number',
            'complete_name',
            'admin',
            'staff',
            'is_active',
            'password',
            'password2'
        ),
    }),
)
```

the problem is, when I try to create a user from admin panel. the panel displays this error:

> Please correct the error below.

[image]

and the first field is highlighted.

but it doesn't show any error messages that i've created. 
how to find what is the validation error?

**Edited** 
following is User model and manager.

```
class UserManger(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, phone_number, email=None, password=None, admin=False, staff=False):
        if not phone_number:
            raise ValueError('You need to enter your phone number without zero at beginning.')
        if not check_phone_number(phone_number):
            raise ValueError('You should enter your phone number correctly.')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('You need to enter a password')

        user_obj = self.model(
            phone_number=phone_number,
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.is_active = True
        user_obj.admin = admin
        user_obj.staff = staff
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_contractoruser(self, phone_number, email=None, full_name=None, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            phone_number=phone_number, email=email, password=password,
            staff=True
        )
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, phone_number, email=None, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            phone_number=phone_number, email=email, password=password,
            admin=True, staff=True
            )
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    phone_number = models.CharField('شماره تلفن', unique=True, max_length=11)

    email = models.EmailField('آدرس ایمیل', max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    complete_name = models.CharField('نام کامل', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    expertise = models.ForeignKey(ServiceCategory, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='تخصص')
    image_profile = models.ImageField('عکس کاربر', blank=True, null=True, upload_to='profile-images')
    timestamp = jModels.jDateTimeField('تاریخ عضویت', auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('فعال بودن کاربر', default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField('پیمانکار بودن کاربر', default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField('ادمین بودن کاربر', default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', ]

    objects = UserManger()
```

Comment: Please provide your user model and form.

Comment: @not2acoder I don't use form. as you see in the code, I commented the add_form.

Comment: Have you customised the user model? Can you show it ?

Comment: @not2acoder yes i have. see the second snippet, after UserManager, User class is available.

Comment: trying adding email to the add_fieldsets, as you have mentioned it in the REQUIRED_FIELDS in your model.